# How to remotely debug OWA add-in on Android

Tags: android, office365, outlook-web-app

I'm currently working on an add-in for OWA for desktop and mobile.

I have some issues when testing on my device and so I would like to use my desktop browser's Developer Tools to debug the JS and check the HTML / CSS.

Is there a solution to do so with my device or with an Android emulator ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried any of the Android browser emulators, but I've found the Emulation modes in Internet Explorer's dev tools to be very helpful.  The various options for document mode, browser profile, user agent string, orientation and resolution should simulate most scenarios.  Note that I believe that these are what are used by the testers at the Office Store who review add-ins submitted for publishing.

Otherwise I've relied on very liberal usage of logging to the console, but debugging JavaScript with the Outlook client from Visual Studio is the easiest by far.

This option may be helpful as well:

HOW TO: Debug Office Add-in In Office Clients without Visual Studio: https://www.itunity.com/article/debug-office-addin-office-clients-visual-studio-2783

Comment: Hi,

My design issues are very "OWA for Android" specific so I can't close my question but I found the article very interesting and helpful, thanks a lot !